# Reentrancy is not allowed in micro C

Tags: embedded, pic

i faced a strange error while using micro C to program pic16f77a  micro controller

```
1- 64 365 Reentrancy is not allowed: function 'I2C1_Repeated_Start' called from two threads __Lib_I2C_c34.c
2- 77 365 Reentrancy is not allowed: function 'SPI1_Write' called from two threads __Lib_SPI_c345.c
```

I am not using any of this functions in my code. I just write a code depends on timer0 , so where is the problem?

Comment: Post the entire build log including the command invokations so we can see how you are invoking the compiler and the exact diagnostic info. Use code markup for the log to preserve formatting and line breaks.

Comment: I guess your are calling the same functions in your ISR and in your mainloop.

Comment: Are you using any I²C and SPI function of a library?

Comment: @Mike  i didn't  call ant of them and i am not including I2C or SPI libraries .

Comment: @thebusybee NO , i didnt

Comment: @Clifford its my first question here and i dont know how to post the code in a good way ?

Comment: That's not hard: Copy-n-paste it into your question, mark all its lines and click the button that looks like a pair of curly braces. You can [edit] your question, there is that little link on the left below your question. Please try to reduce your code to a [example], do not post all of it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about micro C but in xc8 this is related to compiled vs 'normal' stack. You can't be re-entrant with a compiled stack. Xc8, again, generates a warning in this case, and creates a second copy of a function.

Edit(add): The function names in error messages most likely come from MCC.

Comment: i am sorry but i don't know what is MCC and i dont know how this error bring up while i am not using any of these functions or libraries

Comment: That is not really the question however.  The problem is linking code that he is not using intentionally.